# how to add some code to javascript while it is runnig on another window

Tags: javascript, playlist

How to add some code to javascript while it is running in another window, for example if some songs are playing using javascript in another window then how to add another song to the playlist i.e to javascript

var myPlaylist=[{mp3:'path of the song',title:'title of the song'},{mp3:'path of the song',title:'title of the song'},{mp3:'path of the song',title:'title of the song'}];           
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(body).ttwmusicplayer(myPlayList,)

});

by using this script some songs are playing in the pop-up window.....
and my problem is how to add a another song to the playlist i.e in pop-up window when some button is clicked on the parent window.

Comment: Can you describe this more or add some examples?

Comment: http://www.codebasehero.com/files/music-player/demo/       this is the player i'm using

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LocalStorage. You can share your data between tabs through it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: @andeersg I know no ways to solve described issue for cross domains. Also, guess, it wasn't about it.

Comment: Yes, but the question is to vague, so i felt it was important information.